# Accessing set_secure_random_alphanum() function from a lua script in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm using Nginx 1.6.1 with `lua-module` and `set-misc-module`.

I need to generate a secure random key as for a session id. I think the `set_secure_random_alphanum` function is a good way to do this.

The key generation should happens in a lua script but I did not manage to find a way to call `set_secure_random_alphanum` from the script.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [ndk.set_var](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ndk.set_var.DIRECTIVE) api, for example:

```
local id = ndk.set_var.set_secure_random_alphanum(16)
```